# Python clean up a daemon process

Tags: python, daemon, resource-cleanup

Using python 3.6.

What is considered best practice regarding clean up of daemon like process or applications?

I'm am aware of context managers, I don't believe they can help in this scenario.

Considering this code:

```
from time import sleep
import asyncio

class RequiresResource(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('test.txt', 'w')


    async def run_forever(self, msg, s=5):
        """Lets assume this function needs self.file"""
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(s)
            print(msg)


    def must_be_called(self):
        print('I was called')
        self.file.close()

resource = RequiresResource()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(resource.run_forever('Foo', 2), resource.run_forever('Bar',3)))
finally:
    resource.must_be_called()
```

`resource.must_be_called()` never gets called

How would you handle this?

Comment: Under what conditions would you *expect* your `must_be_called()` method to be called? After all, under normal circumstances your `run_forever()` calls do just that.

Comment: This is abstracted from my actual problem, where I have a continuous data stream from a `http session`. Where I want to stream forever until the process is shutdown/killed. At which point I'd like to call `session.close`

Comment: sounds like you need an on exit hook

Comment: Googling 'python on exit hook`  I found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-exit-hook Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem with this code is. It works perfectly for me - and properly calls `must_be_called` when I hit it with a Keyboard Interrupt (ctrl + C).

Comment: Hmm, I ran it in PyCharm. An confirmed you are correct, when I ran it from a shell. Ok good, thank you!